# C# version of SUDS?

Tags: c#, .net, python, web-services, soap

I was using Python SUDS a couple of years ago to connect to a web service for smoke testing purposes. The Python scripts would use SUDS to connect to the WSDL file and send soap messages to the web service. Then SUDS would parse the returning XML. Is there a way or library that exists, that would do the same thing in C# (.NET)?

I have seen WCF but I'm not sure that if it is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a Web Reference to your web service in Visual Studio will create a proxy for you that does this.

Alternatively, you can use the WSDL.EXE tool that you get with Visual Studio to generate a proxy via a command line.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that ServiceStack does that but it's a Service Framework so what I understand is that you also need to implement your service using ServiceStack.

http://www.servicestack.net/